# Issue with previous/old JTable data accessible from new JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I am developing a Java Swing GUI application which consists of the following high level component hierarchy - `JFrame` contains Main `JPanel` which contains Filter `JPanel` and DB Query Results `JPanel`.  Once the user enters specific filter values and selects the Submit button from the Filter Panel, the appropriate database query is executed and the results (if any) are passed to a method that generates the DB Query Results Panel displayed below the Filter Panel.

The problem I am running into is if a successive database query is performed that returns less data/rows than the previous database query the DB Query Results Panel which contains a `JScrollPane` built from a `JTable` of the processed results looks correct, but if I click/drag the mouse below the latest returned/displayed result rows the previous data rows appear and the right hand scroll list bar appears if enough old data rows are presented.  Following is the code or code snippet associated with the database query method that passes the `ResultSet` to the method that builds the Result Panel.  Hope it is enough to indicate the issue.  I have tried everything found on the internet so far (calls to various methods `repaint()`, `remove()`, `revalidate()`, ...) to no success.

Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

```
public void submitQuery(){
 //...Establish database connection
 //...Generate database query based on provided filters
try{
  Statement stmt = db_connection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( generated query );
  buildDataResultPanel(rs):
  frame.validate();
} 
//... handle exceptions
}

public void buildDataResultPanel(ResultSet rs){
  final JLabel resultsHeader = new JLabel("Database Query Results");
  Vector<Vector<String>> resultRows = null;
  JTable resultsTable = null;

  try{
     if ( (rs != null) && (rs.isBeforeFirst() ){
        resultRows = new Vector<Vector<String>> ();
        while (rs.next){
          Vector<String> resultRow = new Vector<String>();
          resultRow.add(rs.getString(1));
          //....
          //....
          resultRows.add(resultRow);
        }
     }
     DefaultTableModel resultTableModel = 
                       new DefaultTableModel(resultRows, columnNames);
     resultsTable = new JTable(resultTableModel);
     resultsTable.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
     resultsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(
         new Dimension(1100,500));
     resultsTable.getColumnModel.getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(100);
     //....
     //....
     JPanel resultsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
     GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
     gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
     gbc.weightx = 1;
     gbc.weighty = 1;
     gbc.gridx = 0;
     gbc.gridy = 0;
     resultsPanel.add(resultsHeader, gbc);
     gbc.gridx = 0;
     gbc.gridy++;
     JScrollPane resultsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultsTable);
     resultsPanel.add(resultsScrollPane, gbc);

     mainPanel.add(resultsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     mainPanel.validate();
  }
  //.... handle exceptions
  }
```

Comment: *"The problem I am running into.."*  I'm more interested in the question you are asking.  .. What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're removing the previous `JScrollPane`/`JTable` and what you are seeing is a z-ordering issue, that is, all the previous `JScrollPane`/`JTable`s are still visible on the screen and are competing with each other visibility.

Instead of creating a new `JScrollPane`/`JTable` each time, simply create a new `TableModel` and apply it to the pre-existing `JTable`

Comment: I am an old school C/C++ developer and have learned through experience to always create new instances of objects to insure that you are using new memory area and will not reference old objects/data.  I thought by performing the following line of code that I was creating a new TableModel:

Comment: Not sure why I could not edit the previous comment, anyways I thought I was creating a new TableModel by the following line of code: DefaultTableModel resultTableModel = 
                       new DefaultTableModel(resultRows, columnNames);

Comment: I attempted to make the previous mentioned changes (create JScrollPane and JTable once), and apply new TableModel each time to existing JTable to no success.  Would you possibly be able to provide me with some guidance/code snippet example.  Thanks, Russell

Comment: You are creating a new `TableModel`, but you're also creating a new `JTable`, `JPanel` and `JScrollPane`, which is unnecessary, when the only thing changing is the `TableModel`.  Simply create a new instance of the `TableModel` and apply it to the already existing a `JTable`.  This is how MVC works